# Change DataType of DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, value-type

I have done a Tool that selects some data from a VFP-Database and inserts everything in a DataGrid. (until here everything works...) At this point I would like to change some values of a specific Column but I get everytime an error, saying that the type is not correct because "decimal" is expected and I am inserting some strings...

I'll explain with an example. There is a column containing the row id, then I have another column containing all user id's and so on. What I need is to change the user id with the user name. (only in my DataGrid, not in the Database) That means, that for example the cell containing user-id "1234" is changed into "John". My problem: at runtime the column containing "1234" is declared as "decimal" so I can not enter any string.

I have tried to use all of theese three commands (one by one, not all together):

```
1) dataGrid.Columns["hot_kunde"].CellTemplate.ValueType = typeof(string);
2) dataGrid.Columns["hot_kunde"].ValueType = typeof(string);
3) for (int i = 0; i < dataGrid.RowCount; i++)
   {
       dataGrid.Rows[i].Cells[1].ValueType = typeof(String);
       dataGrid.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = "test";
   }
```

When I use a MessageBox to show the new changed type, it throws "System.String". Alltough it fires an exception (as said before "expecting decimal") when trying to change the value with a string. (for example "test")

Am I missing something??

Thank you for any reply

---

### EDIT:

Ok, here is my actual code:

```
public void SqlQuery(String SQL)
    {
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=VFPOLEDB;" +
                                "Data Source=" + Properties.Settings.Default.DBCcontainer + "\\drive.dbc;" +
                                "Collating Sequence=machine;" +
                                "Password=;" +
                                "Mode=Share Deny Write;";
        conn.Open();

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(SQL, conn);

        try
        {
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable DTable = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(DTable);

            dataGrid.DataSource = DTable;
            conn.Dispose();
            conn.Close();

            dataGrid.Columns["hot_kunde"].CellTemplate.ValueType = typeof(string);
            //dataGrid.Columns["hot_kunde"].ValueType = typeof(string);
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGrid.RowCount; i++)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(dataGrid.Rows[i].Cells["hot_kunde"].ValueType.ToString());
                //dataGrid.Rows[i].Cells[1].ValueType = typeof(String);
                dataGrid.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = "test";
            }
        }
        catch (OleDbException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message + "\r\n------------------------------------------------------------\r\n\r\n" + e.Source, "OleDbException", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

And this is the SQL-String I'm passing to the function:

```
SqlQuery("SELECT hot_erldat, hot_kunde, hot_bez, hot_text, hot_losung FROM hotges.dbf WHERE UPPER(SUBSTR(hot_bez, 1, " + sup.Length + ")) = '" + sup + "'");
```

Well, here you can't see it, but "hot_kunde" is the user-id and it is defined as decimal in the database but I don't need the user-id, instead I need the name. How can I do this operation?

Comment: I don't think this will work if your DB field is meant to have a decimal value. The error message is telling you so.

Comment: Post the code responsible for filling the DataGridView. Maybe we can find some workaround.

Comment: Ok, thank you PaulG.
@Adam I have edited my first question.

Perhaps you guys have an idea how I could do it in an other way...

Comment: What if you add another column for name and hide the id field?

Comment: ooh... good idea! i had not even thought of this :P
I'll try it out. Thank you for the hint.